# How can I upgrade to Java 1.8 on an Amazon Linux Server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I tried sudo yum update but it just keeps java "1.7.0_75". I need 1.8 for it to work with another application but can't figure out how to upgrade it.
Do I need to manually install it somehow? There's not much information on this on the internet as far as I can see.
Specs:

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.5.4.0.53.amzn1-x86_64 u75-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

When I try update now:

```
[ec2-________]$ sudo yum update
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
No packages marked for update
```

Is there anything else I need to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Should be on Server Fault

Comment: I'll ask over there thank you, didn't even know what server fault was..

Comment: Major java versions are separate packages.You would need to install `java-1.8.0-openjdk`.

Comment: Hello,  I installed that and it says it's installed correctly, but when I check java version it is still 1.7

Answer (score 10):

You need to uninstall the previous java version, to do this, install java 1.8 with:

> yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64

and then uninstall the previous java version, in my case:

> yum erase java-1.7.0-openjdk

P.S: java-1.7.0-openjdk is installed on Amazon Linux AMI by default .

Regards!

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
sudo /usr/sbin/alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/javac
sudo yum remove java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

check Java current version

java -version
install Java 1.8

sudo yum install java-1.8.0
change Java version

sudo alternatives --config java